# I need to sort data from an array into UITableView sections with the date as the section header with any date as todays date as 'Today' etc

Tags: swift, uitableview, date, struct

So I have an array of data that was created with a struct e.g.:

```
struct Struct {
  let id = UUID()
  let name: String
  let date: Date
  let amount: Float
}
extension Struct {
  init(name: String, amount: Float) {
    self.name = name
    self.date = Date()
    self.amount = amount
  }
}
```

This is then used to create an array of structs e.g.:

```
var structs = [Struct]()
let name = ["struct1", "struct2", "struct3"]
let amount = [1, 2, 3]

let structsCount = name.count
for i in 0..<structsCount {
  structs.append(Struct(name: name[i], amount: Float(amount[i])))
}
```

This is just used for dummy data so I understand that the date will always be the current date.
I have seen suggestions of arranging the `structs` array into a Dictionary using the date property and then sorting the Dictionary by that date.
I just can't seem to get this to work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to arrange your structs into matrix `[[Struct]]`, so you will have next array `[[Struct(name: 1, date: 20-10-2019, amount: 1), Struct(name: 2, date: 20-10-2019, amount: 2)], [Struct(name: 3, date: 20-10-2019, amount: 3)], ...]`

then you can use it to populate `UITableView`.

You can do with code below

```
//Since Set contains unique values, you will get all dates
let dates = Set(structs.map { $0.date })
var resultStructs: [[Struct]] = []
for date in dates {
    var array: [Struct] = []
    for element in structs {
        if date == element.date {
            array.append(element)
        }
    }
    resultStructs.append(array)
}
```

now `resultStructs` will contain array `[[Struct]]` arranged by date. Sort it to get correct order and populate `UITableView`